# Fluent Nhibernate Mapping

Tags: .net, nhibernate, mapping, fluent

I have 2 classes, MasterItem and ItemUOM.
ItemUOM is a view that i've mapped and MasterItem a straight forward table.
Is it possible to reference MasterItem in ItemUOM.

ItemUOM class:

```
 public class ItemUOM : EntityBase<ItemUOM>
{
    public virtual string ItemAlias { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string UOM { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal PackSize { get; set; }
    public virtual long MasterItemID { get; set; }
    **public virtual DomainEntities.MasterItem MasterItem { get; set; }**
}
```

ItemUOM mapping

```
    public ItemUOMMapping()
    {
        Table("View_ItemUOM");
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Code);
        Map(x => x.ItemAlias);
        Map(x => x.UOM);
        Map(x => x.PackSize);
    }
```

How can I reference to class "MasterItem".

Thanks Francois

Answer (score 1):

You need to **remove** MasterItemID and use `References(x => x.MasterItem)`, etc.

Comment: I dont have a reference to the key, remeber this is a SQL View.

Comment: I need to tell the mapping that MasterItemID maps back to tabel MasterItem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you need a regular [many-to-one](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#References_.2F_many-to-one):

```
public ItemUOMMapping()
{
    Table("View_ItemUOM");
    Id(x => x.ID);
    Map(x => x.Code);
    Map(x => x.ItemAlias);
    Map(x => x.UOM);
    Map(x => x.PackSize);
    References(x => x.MasterItem)
        .Column("MasterItemID");
}
```

And MasterItem should have its own mapping where you specify all its properties.

Comment: I get a Invalid column name 'MasterItemID'. If I take the sql query and execute it in SQL it works.